# Invalid Route when routing in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I'm trying to create a new route, and for the life of me can't figure out why it's returning an `invalid route` response.

Here is the route (there are no filters on this route):

```
Route::get('api/books/{bookId}', 'BookController@getBook');
```

Here is the URL I use to query this route:

> https://fakeBookSite.com/api/books/2?apiKey=someRandomKey

What is even stranger is that this route works:

```
Route::get('api/books', 'BookController@getBooks');
```

The route that works is listed BEFORE the one that doesn't, which is best practice in my understanding.

**Even stranger**, when I comment out the routes that do work, they **still work** when queried. I can only imagine that this is a caching issue, but as you will see below, I have cleared all the caches that I know about.

I have ran `composer dump` and `composer clear` and `php artisan cache:clear`. Your thoughts are highly appreciated!

Comment: Do your other routes work?

Comment: They do, yes. Please see edited question. I can get all the books; I just can't get a particular book

Comment: Super weird. I completely had to close all the files I was editing and restart my FTP... It's working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was actually a result of my FTP connection. I suppose that the files I was editing were not actually changing the server files. This just goes to show that if you feel you've tried everything, just 'restarting' is the way to go!